# "buzz building" & "pull a scoop on"

Tags: phrases

From NPR: [The Beatles' Yearlong Journey To 'The Ed Sullivan Show'](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=273085051)

> Remember now, the Beatles' U.S. arrival is still more than a month away. With the ***buzz building***, NBC's Jack Parr ***pulled a scoop on*** rival Ed Sullivan on January 3rd that almost derailed the Beatles express.

What's the meaning of "buzz building" and "pull a scoop on"?

Comment: Did you look up _buzz_ and _scoop_ in the dictionary? A question like this would be better if you did, and shared what you found there – much like [this guy did](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/147143).

Comment: @J.R. Thank you. In fact, I have looked up these words in the dictionary for a long time, but didn't find a proper interpretation. Indeed sharing is a good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NOAD:

> **buzz**: an atmosphere of excitement and activity
>
> **scoop** *informal* a piece of news published by a newspaper or broadcast by a television or radio station in advance of its rivals.

The Beatles were coming, and many people were excited. Hence, the anticipation was growing; the buzz was building.

Parr and Sullivan both ran evening entertainment shows. Sullivan booked the Beatles, and much of the U.S. was excited. On his show, Parr played a video of the Beatles beforehand, thus trying to make it not such a big deal when the Beatles played live one month later.

Perhaps the most interesting word in the passage, from an English learner's perspective, is *pull*. I'm not sure I'd heard of *pull a scoop* before (then again, I'm not in the news business). However, I did find this in NOAD, and I think it's relevant:

> **pull a fast one** *informal* try to gain an unfair advantage

In other words, Parr tried to gain an advantage (in the television ratings) by (perhaps unfairly) showing the Beatles on television shortly before they were to appear on his rival's program. He pulled a scoop.

Answer (score -1):

buzz building-It usually means that the anticipation of the people grew higher,and the excitement kept increasing as the day of their arrival grew nearer

pulled a scoop on-means he some exclusive,never before seen footage was featured in his show.This footage probably reduced the rating of his rivals show and also the official plans made by the beatles was ruined